# extract the correlation matrix for the factors in the psych package's fa.poly function

Tags: r, data-structures, extract

I'm working from [caracal's great example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/looking-for-a-step-through-an-example-of-a-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data/32136#32136) conducting a factor analysis on dichotomous data and I'm now struggling to extract the factors from the object produced by the `psych` package's `fa.poly` function.

Can anyone help me extract the factors from the `fa.poly` object (and look at the correlation)?

Please see [caracal's example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/looking-for-a-step-through-an-example-of-a-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data/32136#32136) for the working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example you create an object with:

```
faPCdirect <- fa.poly(XdiNum, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")    # polychoric FA
```

so somewhere in faPCdirect there is what you want. I recommend using `str()` to inspect the structure of `faPCdirect`

```
> str(faPCdirect)

List of 5
 $ fa   :List of 34
  ..$ residual    : num [1:6, 1:6] 4.79e-01 7.78e-02 -2.97e-0...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" ...
  ..$ dof         : num 4
  ..$ fit      
      ...skip stuff....
  ..$ BIC         : num 4.11
  ..$ r.scores    : num [1:2, 1:2] 1 0.0508 0.0508 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "MR2" "MR1"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "MR2" "MR1"
  ..$ R2          : Named num [1:2] 0.709 0.989
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "MR2" "MR1"
  ..$ valid       : num [1:2] 0.819 0.987
  ..$ score.cor   : num [1:2, 1:2] 1 0.212 0.212 1
```

So this says that this object is a list of five, with the first element called `fa` and that contains an element called `score.cor` that is a 2x2 matrix. I think what you want is the off diagonal.

```
> faPCdirect$fa$score.cor
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.2117457
[2,] 0.2117457 1.0000000
```

Comment: Do you know how is this correlation is being calculated? Is it Pearson correlation?